# Using json_array_elements() to break out rows with elements of JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table of the following format with just one column. There are around 700 entries in total, here are 5 samples:

```
{"year":"2021","category":"chemistry","laureates":[{"id": "1002", "firstname": "Benjamin", "surname": "List", "motivation": "\"for the development of asymmetric organocatalysis\"", "share": "2"}, {"id": "1003", "firstname": "David", "surname": "MacMillan", "motivation": "\"for the development of asymmetric organocatalysis\"", "share": "2"}],"reason":null}
{"year":"2021","category":"economics","laureates":[{"id": "1007", "firstname": "David", "surname": "Card", "motivation": "\"for his empirical contributions  to labour economics\"", "share": "2"}, {"id": "1008", "firstname": "Joshua", "surname": "Angrist", "motivation": "\"for their methodological contributions to the analysis  of causal relationships\"", "share": "4"}, {"id": "1009", "firstname": "Guido", "surname": "Imbens", "motivation": "\"for their methodological contributions to the analysis  of causal relationships\"", "share": "4"}],"reason":null}
{"year":"2021","category":"literature","laureates":[{"id": "1004", "firstname": "Abdulrazak", "surname": "Gurnah", "motivation": "\"for his uncompromising and compassionate penetration of the effects of colonialism and the  fate of the refugee in the gulf between cultures and continents\"", "share": "1"}],"reason":null}
{"year":"2021","category":"peace","laureates":[{"id": "1005", "firstname": "Maria", "surname": "Ressa", "motivation": "\"for their efforts to safeguard freedom of expression, which  is a precondition for democracy and lasting peace\"", "share": "2"}, {"id": "1006", "firstname": "Dmitry", "surname": "Muratov", "motivation": "\"for their efforts to safeguard freedom of expression, which  is a precondition for democracy and lasting peace\"", "share": "2"}],"reason":null}
{"year":"2021","category":"physics","laureates":[{"id": "999", "firstname": "Syukuro", "surname": "Manabe", "motivation": "\"for the physical modelling of Earth’s climate, quantifying variability and reliably predicting global warming\"", "share": "4"}, {"id": "1000", "firstname": "Klaus", "surname": "Hasselmann", "motivation": "\"for the physical modelling of Earth’s climate, quantifying variability and reliably predicting global warming\"", "share": "4"}, {"id": "1001", "firstname": "Giorgio", "surname": "Parisi", "motivation": "\"for the discovery of the interplay of disorder and fluctuations in physical systems from atomic to planetary scales\"", "share": "2"}],"reason":"for groundbreaking contributions to our understanding of complex physical systems"}
```

I want to print the output in this format:

| year | category | r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2021" | "chemistry" | {"id": "1002", "firstname": "Benjamin", "surname": "List", "motivation": ""for the development of asymmetric organocatalysis"", "share": "2"} |
| "2021" | "chemistry" | {"id": "1003", "firstname": "David", "surname": "MacMillan", "motivation": ""for the development of asymmetric organocatalysis"", "share": "2"} |
| "2021" | "economics" | {"id": "1007", "firstname": "David", "surname": "Card", "motivation": ""for his empirical contributions to labour economics"", "share": "2"} |
| "2021" | "economics" | {"id": "1008", "firstname": "Joshua", "surname": "Angrist", "motivation": ""for their methodological contributions to the analysis of causal relationships"", "share": "4"} |
| "2021" | "economics" | {"id": "1009", "firstname": "Guido", "surname": "Imbens", "motivation": ""for their methodological contributions to the analysis of causal relationships"", "share": "4"} |

I was able to get the output above with the following query:

```
SELECT tuple->'year' AS year, tuple->'category' AS category,json_array_elements(tuple->'laureates') FROM prizes LIMIT 5;
```

What I want is to output all values in the table with a query like:

```
SELECT tuple->'year' AS year, tuple->'category' AS category,json_array_elements(tuple->'laureates') FROM prizes;
```

When I run this query I get this error:

> ```
> cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar
> ```

I don't understand why this is happening and how I would go about outputting all possible elements.

Comment: What that means is that there is some row in your table for which the `laureates` column is not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) can only be used with JSON *arrays*, split cases and `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT tuple->'year' AS year, tuple->'category' AS category, json_array_elements(tuple->'laureates') AS r
FROM   prizes
WHERE  json_typeof(tuple->'laureates') = 'array'
UNION ALL
SELECT tuple->'year' AS year, tuple->'category' AS category, tuple->'laureates'
FROM   prizes
WHERE  json_typeof(tuple->'laureates') IS DISTINCT FROM 'array';
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

> `json_typeof` ( `json` ) → `text`
> [...]
>
> Returns the type of the top-level JSON value as a text string.
> Possible types are `object`, `array`, `string`, `number`, `boolean`,
> and `null`. (The `null` result should not be confused with an SQL
> NULL; [...])

Note the use of `IS DISTINCT FROM` in the second leg. The operator `<>` would eliminate rows with `(tuple->'laureates') IS NULL`.

#### `jsonb_path_query()` in Postgres 12 or later

With [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) we don't need to split cases
([like Edouard suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799218/939860)). But to include rows without `laureate`, we need to `LEFT JOIN` to it:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.tuple->>'year' AS year, p.tuple->>'category' AS category, l.r
FROM   prizes p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query((tuple->'laureates')::jsonb, '$[*]', '{"foo":"bar"}') AS l(r) ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b2a30b9a870567ad99c2f7ec42e2ac43)*

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PostGreSQL version 12 or above, then you can use `jsonb_path_query` instead of `json_array_elements` like this :

```
SELECT tuple->>'year'
     , tuple->>'category'
     , jsonb_path_query((tuple->'laureates') :: jsonb, '$[*]')
  FROM prizes
```

`jsonb_path_query` is going to break down `tuple->'laureates'` when it is a json array, but is won't fail when `tuple->'laureates'` is not a json array.

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fddc24d159e10b33ddb6900a4f4faddf).

see the SQL/JSON Path Language in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH).

Comment: `jsonb_path_query()` is actually more elegant. This formulation eliminates rows without laureate though. I added an alternative to my answer.